# How to improve val_loss and val_acc

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am training convolutional neural network (using for `segmentation`). And I have a problem with validation results (`val_loss`, `val_acc` - in network for segmentation is using term `val_dice_coef`) because there is only a minimal change and the result is not improving compared to `acc`  - `dice_coef` and `loss`.

I am using [this](https://github.com/nikhilroxtomar/Deep-Residual-Unet/blob/master/Deep%20Residual%20UNet.ipynb) code example with own optimizer - my parameters:

```
total_number_of_data = 3547 #val + training data
epochs = 400
image_size = 128
batch_size = 2
val_data_size = 400

opt = optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.0000001, decay=1e-6)
```

Results after `350` epochs:

```
epoch |     dice_coef      |        loss         |      val_loss      |   val_dice_coef
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     | 0.5633156299591064 | 0.43668392300605774 | 0.4752978980541229 | 0.5247021317481995
350   | 0.9698152542114258 | 0.03018493764102459 | 0.3346560299396515 | 0.6653439402580261
```

What should I do?

Comment: there is a lot that could help, but you would have to add more details, there is no single simple answer - your data can be unbalanced, maybe you have too few data, did you divide the data to train and val by hand? - you could have added a bias, are you using a net model fit for the task? what are the hyperparameters like learning rate etc. the question as it stands is too vague for anyone to answer

Comment: @DerteTrdelnik check my edit now please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their is not any Particular sol you have to try all possible case here .But I tell you more general process that maximum grandmaster follow.

```
def build_lrfn(lr_start=0.00001, lr_max=0.0008, 
               lr_min=0.00001, lr_rampup_epochs=20, 
               lr_sustain_epochs=0, lr_exp_decay=.8):
    lr_max = lr_max * strategy.num_replicas_in_sync

    def lrfn(epoch):
        if epoch < lr_rampup_epochs:
            lr = (lr_max - lr_start) / lr_rampup_epochs * epoch + lr_start
        elif epoch < lr_rampup_epochs + lr_sustain_epochs:
            lr = lr_max
        else:
            lr = (lr_max - lr_min) * lr_exp_decay**(epoch - lr_rampup_epochs - lr_sustain_epochs) + lr_min
        return lr

    return lrfn
```

```
lrfn = build_lrfn()
lr_schedule = tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(lrfn, verbose=1)


history = model.fit(
    train_dataset, 
    epochs=EPOCHS, 
    callbacks=[lr_schedule],
    steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
    validation_data=valid_dataset
)
```

for more optimizer i always follow this one [link](https://keras.io/optimizers/)

In my opinion Adam recently work best for your model

Comment: I am getting an error: `NameError: name 'strategy' is not defined` at this line: `lr_max = lr_max * strategy.num_replicas_in_sync`

Comment: Replace by numeric value

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/ganeshmundra/average-efficientnet   this is my kernel notebook where I used this optimizer

Comment: Thank you! I got it!

Comment: Excuse me, do you have any other improvements? Now I have reuslt after 118 epochs: `dice_coef: 0.9923152328,  loss: 0.007684784476, val_loss: 0.3029838502, val_dice_coef: 0.6970160604` - using Adam optimizer and your part of code using `tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler`

Comment: And for strategy I tried to use this type of strategy - `strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()`, which strategy is better ? I am training on GPU not TPU (as you in kaggle)

Comment: Bro ,their is not any particular model or strategy that you follow and get highest accuracy .

Comment: what type of data you have  Images,Numerical.give me reference of your data I will try in free time .

Comment: either you search on kaggle in data section .may be you find any kernel

Comment: I have Images with their masks (black and white images)